# Granting PHP permission to send/receive requests

Tags: ubuntu, php, permissions, ubuntu-12.04, socket

I've written a PHP websockets server based on this library: https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

This library operates as a server, and handles all incoming requests.  The client can connect when I'm running locally (connecting to address `127.0.0.1:9300`), but I'm unable to connect if my client is not on the machine running the server.  I've tried turning off my firewall; is there another privilege I need to grant PHP in order for it to be able to receive and respond to websocket communication?

I'm running PHP5, Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, and connecting with Google Chrome (latest).

Comment: I've updated your other question for the same problem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 From line 62 of https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/server.php
```

> // for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change
>   // this to your LAN IP or  external IP, 
>   // alternatively use:
>   gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
>
> $Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);

change this line to,

```
 $Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 9300);
```

or the IP to your LAN IP and try.

Answer (score 1):

The file `server.php` contains the answer to your problem

```
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);
```

Changing the last line to whatever the public facing IP address of your server s will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

just edit the server.php; right now it listens on the loop-back only [ $Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300); ]. change it to listen to all ips [0.0.0.0?] or at least one ip assigned to the network interface [ eth0? ] of your server.